# Dealing with large amounts of "IF"s

Tags: vb6

I have a large block of ifs in my code that I do not want to put into an array as I need them to have unique names.

How would I go about making a much smaller piece of code for this block of IFs?

```
If chkPO.Value = True Then
    ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
End If

If chkGRN.Value = True Then
    ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
End If

If chkSO.Value = True Then
    ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
End If

etc

etc

etc
```

Comment: If chkSO.Value = True Or chkGRN.Value = True Or chkSO.Value = True  Then
    ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
End If

Comment: That's not exactly the same thing, @MGG_Soft, since the conditions aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do is get rid of the superfluous `= True` bits. The whole point of boolean values is that it's unnecessary to compare them with other boolean values - you just say `if something` or `if not something`. Otherwise, where do you stop? Something like:

```
If ((chkSO.Value = True) = True) = True Then
```

ad infinitum?

Keep in mind that the value of the standard checkboxes (assuming they're the ones you're using) is an integer that may be 0 for unchecked, 1 for checked and 2 for greyed out. Hence your code (and mine) are relying on the implicit conversion to boolean values. That won't be a problem if you don't ever grey out the boxes in your code as 0 (unchecked) will be coerced into false. However, greyed out will be treated as if the bos was checked.

If you allow greying out, you may want to modify the code to take that into account. How to do so depends on how you want to treat the greyed out checkboxes and that's a decision only you can make. If you're not ever setting the state to greyed out, you can ignore this, and the previous, paragraph.

Then, assuming you cannot use arrays (as you state), you can at least use the one-line variant of the `if` statement:

```
If chkPO.Value  Then ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
If chkGRN.Value Then ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
If chkSO.Value  Then ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
```

That should drop your code size by about 75% (based on line count), a substantial amount.

Comment: Thankyou, thats much better to look at :)

Comment: Downvoter, if you'd care to tell me _why_ you think the answer isn't useful, I could fix it.

Comment: Actually, assuming this is the standard VB Checkbox control, this code is not necessarily correct. The Value property of a Checkbox is an Integer - not Boolean, and can take the values: vbUnchecked (=0), vbChecked (=1) and vbGrayed (=2). Note that this means that the original code would not work (vbChecked <> True). In the new code, you are essentially relying on VB auto-converting vbUnchecked to False and vbChecked to True. The thing is that vbGrayed also converts to True. The code would be cleaner (and slightly smaller) if you use the correct comparison.

Comment: @Mark, good point. I was simply commenting on the code supplied by OP and it may be that they never grey out the checkboxes in which case everything will be fine. However, I've added a note to bring this to their attention in case they _do_ grey them out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you should consider using the [IIF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx);

```
ReportTaskCount = IIF(chkPO.Value, ReportTaskCount + 1, ReportTaskCount)
ReportTaskCount = IIF(chkGRN.Value, ReportTaskCount + 1, ReportTaskCount)
```

This might save you time and remain very much readable.

And no need to specify `= True` for each condition, since its a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little much for something so simple, but if you have a hundred of them how about-

```
Private mReportTaskCount As Integer

Private Sub IncrementCount(ByVal blnValue As Boolean)
    If blnValue Then mReportTaskCount = mReportTaskCount + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Whatever()
    IncrementCount chkPO.Value
    IncrementCount chkGRN.Value
    IncrementCount chkSO.Value
    IncrementCount chkBLU.Value
    IncrementCount chkYEL.Value
    IncrementCount chkPUR.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub YourSub()
    ReportTaskCount = CountTrueBooleans (chkPO.Value, chkGRN.Value, chkSO.Value)
End Sub

Public Function CountTrueBooleans (ParamArray Values())
    Dim ret as long
    For i = LBound(aa) To UBound(Values)
        If Values(i) <> 0 Then ret = ret + 1 'checking for "True" and counting them...
    Next
    CountTrueBooleans = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you knew that you would increment ReportTaskCount for all the checked CheckBox controls on the window, you could do the following:

```
Private Sub MakeReportTaskCount()

    Dim ctl As Control

    ReportTaskCount = 0

    For Each ctl In Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
            ReportTaskCount = ReportTaskCount + 1
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could give each CheckBox a special value for its Tag property, e.g. "ReportCountCheck", and do a string comparison instead of the TypeOf check.